# Mongodb data corruption from heroku app cause & prevention

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, heroku, meanjs, mlab

I have a free heroku plan and a nodejs app on the heroku server. The nodejs app is built with meanjs, so the code for mongodb connections is exactly what you would find in the configuration files. I use a mongolab free mongo database to store the data. Occasionally (depending on how much I interact/change code I believe), the mongodb data is corrupted. I believe this to be true because I use a script to register names, and I can always log into them for awhile until I receive a no user/pass error. If I get this error and immediately create a new user, the user can successfully be logged in and out. All of the user data is still in the database. I also have a few other crud modules that use different collections in the same database, and I (so far) have not seen anything happen to that data, or **anything** to **any** of the data besides the password. I don't know where my error is possibly coming from, or what code is relevant, as I haven't touched the config files at all and to my knowledge haven't written any code that looks at user passwords at all. Also, my user object is occasionally empty (user = "") in the markup, but that bug was introduced after the original, I believe while I was trying to find out what was going on. Again, I don't have any clue though, so I included it just in case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I found the cause to my problem.

After I created these users, I go into my Mongolab account and manually edit the roles based on what module I'm working on (doing role based authentication). It is when editing the data that my passwords become corrupted. I don't know why, but I've pinpointed the problem to there. I've messed with some other data, with similar results.